Why can I not add FontFaces from one FontFaceSet to another FontFaceSet?
This is my first StackOverflow post so apologies if it is not very polished and/or straightforward.
Hello, I am trying to copy the FontFaces from one Document to another.  The method by which I am doing it seems to work fine in a Chrome browser, but it will not work for Firefox and Safari (those are the only browsers I have tested it on).  I have narrowed the problem down to this code block.
export async function copyFonts(sourceDoc: Document, targetDoc: Document): Promise<void> {
  const sourceFonts = sourceDoc.fonts;
  const targetFonts = targetDoc.fonts;

  sourceFonts.forEach((font) => {
    if (font instanceof FontFace) {
      targetFonts.add(font);
    }
  })

  await targetFonts.ready;
}

Specifically it's the line targetFonts.add(font) that throws an error.  The error outputted is a DOM exception that says:
FontFaceSet.add: Can't add face to FontFaceSet that comes from an @font-face rule
I have tried adding a check to see if each FontFace in the sourceDoc.fonts FontFaceSet is an instanceof CSSFontFaceRule, and that returns false which is confusing given the DOM Exception.
I have also tried making a deep copy of the FontFace from the sourceDoc and adding that to the targetDoc FontFaceSet, but the issue is that a FontFace constructor expects a source path, and the FontFaces I get from the sourceDoc do not have a source path.  They only have a family and descriptors.
I am also copying the CSS styleSheets from the sourceDoc to the targetDoc.  This is done to keep the spacing and colors correct, but I also have verified that the FontFaces from the sourceDoc are copied to the targetDoc via the styleSheets as well.  They just are not appearing in the targetDoc when I expect the DOM if I only rely on copying over styleSheets, so I definitely need to be copying over the FontFaceSet from the sourceDoc to the targetDoc as far as I can tell.
I would expect to be able to add a FontFace to a FontFaceSet normally across all browsers.  There has been nothing I've found to indicate that browsers cannot support this functionality.  The closest thing I have found that is similar to my problem is this post, but I have the dom.iterable library installed.
Does anyone know what the problem might be?
